# Keep reference to element of std::vector after erasing prior element

Tags: pointers, vector, element

Hiho everibody.
Is there a way to create a pointer to an element of a std::vector but keep the pointer pointing on the same element after deleting one at a lower position?

E.g.:
the vector contains 0,1,2,3,4,5 and my pointer points to position 3, so to number 3.
Now I want to erase lets say the element at position 1.
What I want is that the pointer points automatically at position 2, so still to number 3, without updating it by myself.

Is this possible?
Help would be much apreciated.
Best regards
Ritti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` invalidates iterators on most operations. If you want to keep an iterator referencing an element, use another container, such as `std::list`, which only invalidates iterators referencing the erased element.

Comment: Ok I've just seen that I can't access random elements in a list. Is it slower if I use an iterator? I'm using this for a 3d strategy game, so speed is quite important

Comment: Write code first, then profile. Obviously a `std::vector` will not work at all given your requirements, so you never make it to the profiling stage.